# Dependence of eigen values on parameter of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a matrix in the block form 
$
  A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   A_1 & kA_2\\
   kA_3 & A_4\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

with $A$ being an $(n+m)\times (n+m)$ matrix. $A_1$ has dimension $n\times n$, , $A_2$ has dimension $n\times m$, $A_3$  has dimension $m\times n$ and $A_4$ has dimension $m\times m$.  k is a real number.

For large matrices is there a way to know how the largest and smallest eigen values of $A$ are dependent on the parameter k?